# Debian Squeeze: Left mouse click stops working

Tags: debian, gnome, mouse

After starting a new session in my Debian Squeeze (6.0.4, always updated) running in a VM (VMWare Workstation) there comes the point in time where the left mouse click stops working, so that I cannot resize windows, bring them to front etc.

Sometimes I can switch window focus with the right click or with right-click and
<kbd>Control</kbd> key held at the same time, but then it does not work at all.

Keys are accepted. I do not run anything special, just Emacs, Okular, Thunderbird and such stuff.

Unfortunately I cannot give any sequence of events which reliably creates the
problem.

Is there a known fix to this problem (my googling efforts were not successful)
or do i have to switch to KDE or LXFE?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue and have not found a proper fix for this, 
what I end up doing is `modprobe -r psmouse`, then `modprobe psmouse` to get back control.

Comment: This works for me, but there has got to be a better fix.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the Xorg `vmmouse` driver, at minimum, or have VMware Tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: I could swear I had some text as intro here; now it's gone, and there was no marker that anyone edited it? Maybe I've triggered some of website's auto-delete by saying "me too" or something `:)` Anyways, apologies I've forgotten what my intro should have been ... but basically this is what worked on my system]

```
$ lsusb | grep -i logitech
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c526 Logitech, Inc. Nano Receiver

# search by ID - make sure it's capital letters (or case insensitive)
#
$ find /sys/devices/ -iname '*046d*'
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:046D:C526.0002
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:046D:C526.0003

# look for all refs to "driver" 
# in /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/
#
$ for ix in $(find /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/ -name '*driver*'); do echo $ix; ls -la $ix; done
/sys/devices/..../usb3/3-1/driver
... 22:31 /sys/devices/..../usb3/3-1/driver -> ../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/usb
/sys/devices/..../usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/driver
... 22:46 /sys/devices/..../usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/driver -> ../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/usbhid
/sys/devices/..../usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:046D:C526.0002/driver
... 22:46 /sys/devices/..../usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:046D:C526.0002/driver -> ../../../../../../../bus/hid/drivers/generic-usb
/sys/devices/..../usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/driver
... 22:46 /sys/devices/..../usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/driver -> ../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/usbhid
/sys/devices/..../usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:046D:C526.0003/driver
... 22:46 /sys/devices/..../usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:046D:C526.0003/driver -> ../../../../../../../bus/hid/drivers/generic-usb

# list usb drivers given by `lsmod`
#
$ lsmod | grep usb
usbhid                 41704  0 
hid                    77084  1 usbhid
usb_storage            43946  0 

# it must be `usbhid` that is responsible - unload it:
#
$ sudo modprobe -r usbhid

# at this point, the USB wireless mouse wasn't moving 
# the pointer anymore (but touchpad was; also left click
# on touchpad started working here);
# load `usbhid` again
#
$ sudo modprobe usbhid
```

... and at this point, left click with the wireless USB mouse recovered for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following two lines in your C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\VMware\preferences.ini file:

`pref.motionGrab = "FALSE"`

`pref.motionUngrab = "FALSE"`

Answer found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62925/vmware-mouse-occasionally-held-down-cannot-unclick-left-mouse-stops-working?lq=1)