# VMware mouse occasionally held down (cannot "unclick", left mouse stops working, grab ungrab)

Tags: mouse, vmware

I have Debian 6.0.6 on vmware player. I notice once in a while the mouse just selects everything - like starting from some point to wherever my mouse is currently at. I can't unselect or press any buttons, except right click. And then I still can't select anything, but if I right click the context menu goes away. I know this is really localized, but if someone has seen this issue and can point out where it's from I can make the title more general. After a while the selection goes away and I can click again. I can send signals via VMware but it doesn't seem to help (just got to wait). Any idea what's causing this?

---

Finally,  I noticed that the this was applying to any click when my mouse was held down over the scrollbar and I couldn't click anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this thread:https://superuser.com/questions/155855/mouse-button-gets-stuck-down-in-vmware-guest-os

Though I couldn't find these settings in vmplayer, some more digging and I fixed it by changing VMware's settings in
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\VMware\preferences.ini`

by adding

```
pref.motionGrab = "FALSE"
pref.motionUngrab = "FALSE"
```

Basically, there's a problem with the mouse auto-ungrabbing when the mouse leaves the VM. This makes it so you can't take the mouse away unless you hit the ungrab key combination (ctrl + alt on windows by default). Seems to be working so far.

---

While it was a useful change, and seemed to work, got the error again after a day.

This is my latest solution, from [Debian Squeeze: Left mouse click stops working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34036/debian-squeeze-left-mouse-click-stops-working)

Right click works, so right click on Terminal shortcut. Hover mouse over "open", and hit enter (keyboard works). Type:

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse
```

And that seems to restore the mouse. Don't know what is causing it. There's mention of Xorg... I have it installed... don't know what to do though to make sure it's working. This is my temporary solution, but if anyone knows anything better please let me know.